# neo4j how to display links characteristics between nodes

Tags: neo4j

I would like to represent computer networks and their connectivity between them.
With neo4j server located at `http://localhost:7474` I can represent them like this :[image]

However, I would like to let user see connectivity between nodes. When selecting two servers (purple nodes), it would render the paths between them and pop (as tooltip for instance) firewalling rules implemented on routers (green nodes).

Is it possible to do it with neo4j browser ? Or should I go for another representation library ?

Many thanks!

Comment: Are you looking to let your users use the neo4j browser or are you looking for this representation in some sort of client (web or desktop) application?

Comment: both of them, whatever may get the job done! Many thanks for replying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to provide this functionality as part of an application I would look at using a 3rd party library to handle the display.  A few that I have successfully used in the past to accomplish this sort of thing are:

[Keylines](https://cambridge-intelligence.com/keylines/) (commercial)

[Linkurious](https://linkurio.us/) (commercial)

[Y-Files](https://www.yworks.com/products/yfiles) (commercial)

[Sigma JS](http://sigmajs.org/) (MIT License)

[D3](https://d3js.org/) (BSD)

[VisJS](http://visjs.org/) (MIT-Apache2.0)